# CodeIgniter Pagination with SimpleXML?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is what I have so far, from other sample code I found online. But its not working properly, its not showing me 5 items per page.

```
$feed[] = simplexml_load_file(‘feeds/file.xml’);
$quantity = 5; // items to show per page.
$start = $this->uri->segment(3);
if(!$start) $start = 0;
$data[‘feed’] = array_slice($feed, $start, $quantity);
$config[‘base_url’] = base_url() . ‘welcome/feed/’;
$config[‘uri_segment’] = 3;
$config[‘num_links’] = 25;
$config[‘total_rows’] = count($feed);
$config[‘per_page’] = 5;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$data[‘pages’] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Any help would be good, thank you.

Comment: How many items is it showing you? Also, are you calling this in your view or your controller ?? Please try and add some more description to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$feed[] = simplexml_load_file(‘feeds/file.xml’);
```

to

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file(‘feeds/file.xml’);
```